# how to add a permission to a log file in docker container

Tags: scala, docker, sbt

I am using `logback.xml` for logging logs in sbt project I am using sbt native packager [docker plugin](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html) for creating my project image

i am getting following exception when running the container

```
-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[Interpret-auth] - openFile(/tmp/logs/test-auth.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/logs/test-auth.log (Permission denied)
docker-test-auth-container |    at java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/logs/test-auth.log (Permission denied)
```

here is my logback.xml file

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="Interpret-auth" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <File>/tmp/logs/test-auth.log</File>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %r [%thread] %logger{0} %level - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %r [%thread] %logger{0} %level - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="interpret-auth-logger" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Interpret-auth"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="Interpret-auth"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

and here is my dockerFile setting in build.sbt

```
enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)

enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)

enablePlugins(GatlingPlugin)

dockerExposedPorts := Seq(8083)

dockerChmodType := UserGroupWriteExecute

dockerPermissionStrategy := DockerPermissionStrategy.CopyChown

dockerExposedVolumes := Seq("/tmp/logs")
```

and here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    container_name: docker-keycloak-container
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - JAVA_OPTS_APPEND=-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_script=enabled
    command: -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled

  akkahttpservice:
    image: test-auth:0.0.1
    container_name: docker-test-auth-container
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    depends_on:
      - keycloak
    volumes:
    - /home/logs:/tmp/logs
```

Comment: did you find any solution?